# Capacitor voltage rating in a zener-only stabilized mains supply - 35 V rating OK for 24 V?

Tags: capacitor, mains, zener, maximum-ratings

I have to replace a smoothing capacitor in the "power supply" of a mains operated device. The stabilization is done with two 12 V Zener diodes in series. The supply uses a capacitor and resistor to step down the 230 V and then clamps the voltage using the Zeners. The estimated current draw of the whole circuit is less than 50mA.

The old capacitor was rated 220µF / 50V. I don't have specifications on the old capacitor. I can't even find the manufacturer "GTH". It died, losing almost all of its capacitance.

*Is it acceptable to replace the old capacitor with a (low ESR) capacitor rated for 35V?*

Using a 35V capacitor (for a short test) the device was functional. The expected voltage is 24 V. The reading matched that expectation.

Here is the relevant part of the schematic. The capacitor of interest is **C2**:

[image: Schematic (the power supply section)]

Comment: You don't by any chance know the exact part number of the old capacitor, do you?

Comment: Nope. I've only the PCB - thankfully with component value or model designators printed on the top. The old cap has only these markings: "-40 - 105°C  50V 220µF GTH". I doubt that the old one (older than 10 years) is even a low ESR type.   @mkeith

Comment: I reverse engineered the circuit, the schematic is drawn by me. And yes, the 24V label is actually an output, not an input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case (a Zener-only stabilized mains supply) capacitor cyclic charge and discharge.

Charge through D3 when a half-wave voltage is positive. Discharge on load when a half-wave voltage is negative. Сurrent through the capacitor is essential(appreciable).

Usually, Equivalent series resistance (ESR)  is inversely proportional to the voltage rate of the capacitor at constant capacity.
ESR a 220µF/35V capacitor has greater value as a 220µF/50V capacitor.

Cyclic current and ESR greater value lead to greater heating of the capacitor and this **reduces durable**.

My opinion is replacing permissible but not justified. I do not recommend.

Comment: Can you please explain or elaborate a bit more on "`Equivalent series resistance (ESR) 220µF/35V capacitor has greater value as 220µF/50V capacitor.`"?

Comment: @try-catch-finally , ESR is inversely proportional to the voltage rate of the capacitor at constant capacity. It follows from the datasheet a capacitors or if you look at the table for ESR-metr​.